# How to Maintain a Google App Engine Site in Production

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, development-environment, production-environment

I have been working on a website with Google App Engine for the past few months and I haven't really had to worry about people adding new data or disrupting users when the site went down because I had very few users but I am now planning on rolling the website out to many people.

The site involves users posting topics and I generally when I am making changed on the site I need to have some database entries to work with.  I was wondering what is the most professional and efficient way to develop a website while it is in production and not lose user data or downgrade the user experience all that much.

What would be ideal would be if I could split something like 10% of traffic off onto the new site that I am testing but I haven't found anything like this with GAE.

Comment: just as a question to all of the people who closed this where should I ask a question like this?  I see it isn't exactly the best for SO but I think it is an important question nonetheless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen [traffic splitting](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/trafficsplitting)? It allows you to send a percentage of your users to an alternative app version, E.g. `testing.example.appspot.com`

Comment: okay great this is one of the things I was looking for

Comment: do you know what happens with the datastore here or how I can make sure I am protecting all of my data from potential bugs in the new version?

Comment: All versions use the same datastore, so your data would not be protected from bugs. You could create a new application for testing and copy some user data to that version using the [remote_api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata). I can't think of a way where you could have a segment of your users using a separate set of data -- It would be extremely difficult to keep the data in sync.

Comment: true. I suppose in addition to traffic splitting and as a prelimiary I may need to make a dummy app, thanks for the advice